# PHP / MySQLi / login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

Apologies I know this is going to be a simple answer most likely, but looking for answers I think its confusing me more than just asking the question as there are so many, with confusing or sometimes contradictory answers.

My login script is working as far as connecting to the DB, submitting the $POST usr/pass getting the correct response back.

I now need to use those results to authenticate the user. So.. previously I would have used mysql_num_rows to count the DB response and if 1 then auth. But I appreciate that mysql_num_rows is depreciated and I found another post saying that this is also a weak way to do things now and that it should be avoided.

So what do I use instead?

```
<form id='login' action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <fieldset >
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

        <label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value="" maxlength="50" />

        <BR />

        <label for='password' >Password*:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' value="" maxlength="50" />
        <BR /> 
        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

        </fieldset>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) 
 { 
    $postname = $_POST['username'];
    $postpass = $_POST['password'];
    $postpassMD5 = md5 ($postpass);

    $query = $dbcnx->query("SELECT uid, username, password, ulevel FROM members WHERE     username = '$postname' AND password = '$postpassMD5' ");
    $result = $query->fetch_object();

    $dbcnx->close();

 }
?>
```

Comment: Oh, im also aware that MD5 is weak and will be changing this.

Comment: @aneesh http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: Hi use mysql real escape string to check the users username and password before executing the query.

Comment: `$row_cnt = $query->num_rows;`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to count your result array.

```
if(count($result) > 0 )
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this to protect from MySQL injections:

```
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

Also check

```
$count  = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
    {
      session_start();
      session_register('user_id');
      header("location:user_page.php"); // put your mugallym page name here
    }
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated, and OP already tagged mysqli so I suggest you change to `$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);` [reference](http://us2.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Comment: Those extensions are deprecated and will be removed soon. Onstead use prepared statements, **PDO**, or **mysqli**.  Also use **PHP filter sanitization** instead of old, unhealthy extensions like the ones @candle states.

Comment: Thank I appreciate the answer but as stated previously most of that is now depreciated. Thanks though.